# Creating keyByValue object with plain object natively one line

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object generated from other object keys.
Consuming:

```
const obj = {
    someProp1: 'a',
    someProp2: 'b'
}
```

And desired result:

```
const result = {
    a: {},
    b: {}
}
```

I managed to code this one line with `lodash`, but I want to do it without any dependencies.

```
_.reduce(obj, (acc, value) => _.set(acc, value, {}), {});
```

I tried to make it natively, but the value comes as 'value' property.. By the way - I think `keyBy` should be able to do something like that but I couldn't define an empty object as desired value.

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, value) => Object.assign(acc, {value: {}}), {})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the values ad key with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in single objects and combine all objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const
    object = { someProp1: 'a', someProp2: 'b' },
    result = Object.assign(...Object.values(object).map(k => ({ [k]: {} })));
    
console.log(result);
```

By taking you approach, you could use a computed property instead of `value` as key

```js
const
    object = { someProp1: 'a', someProp2: 'b' },
    result = Object.values(object).reduce((acc, value) =>
        Object.assign(acc, { [value]: {}}), {})
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was good but you forgot `[]`.

#### Your solution:

`Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, value) => Object.assign(acc, {value: {}}), {})`

#### The fix:

`Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, value) => Object.assign(acc, {[value]: {}}), {})`

#### Explanation:

the `[value]` will use the ***value*** of the variable `value` for generating the key name. (Instead of using the word `value` as the key - which you don't want).

---

A more functional way to solve it is not mutating the object `acc` inside the `reduce` operation: (+ changing the names a little bit)

```js
const convertObjectValuesToKeys = obj => Object.values(obj)
    .reduce((result, objectValue) => ({
        ...result,
        [objectValue]:{}
    }), {});
    
const obj = {a: 'a1',b:'b1'};

console.log(convertObjectValuesToKeys(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6's spread and computed keys feature.

```
const obj = {
    someProp1: 'a',
    someProp2: 'b'
}

Object.values (obj)
.reduce ((res,val) => ({...res, [val]: {}}), {})

//{a: {},b: {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
  someProp1: 'a',
  someProp2: 'b'
}

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((map, value) => {map[value] = {}; return map;}, {});

// { a: {}, b: {} }
```

Comment: Hi Seth - thanks for this answer but can you add some context? "Code only" answers are hard to understand.